# Serial Printing Variables at a Specific Time Intervals Prints Size of Array Even If Array Is Not Used

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, arduino

I'm using an Arduino Uno and a CD to simulate an assembly line by attaching sensors on the tops and bottoms of the CD that are read into the Arduino analog ports and count each time a sample passes.  It uses the analog input to register the signal goes high and counts when the signal goes low, like counting the trailing edge of a digital signal.  I want to display the results once an hour and then reset the counters, while storing the old values in an array.  These values are quite large so I declared the array and numbers as unsigned longs.  I troubleshot my code and everything works except for displaying the results at a particular time interval and storing the proper values of the array.  Below is the code I wrote to test this specific section of the program:

```
unsigned long spins[200];
unsigned long positives[200];
unsigned long counter=0;
unsigned long greenCounter=0;
int numberofhours=0;
int timer=0;
int hour=3000;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

}

void loop() {
  timer==millis();

  if (timer%hour==0){  //if the timer reaches 1 hour, it will print the results, store old and clear values for positive tests and CD spins, and print old values

     numberofhours++;

     spins[numberofhours]=counter;
     positives[numberofhours]=greenCounter;

      Serial.print("\n Number of Hours");
      Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.print(numberofhours);  

      /*  for(int i=0; i<numberofhours; i++){
          Serial.print("\n Number of Spins, Hour");
          Serial.print(" ");
          Serial.print(i);
          Serial.print(";");  
          Serial.print(spins[i]);   
          Serial.print("\n Number of Postives, Hour");
          Serial.print(" ");
          Serial.print(i);
          Serial.print(";");  
          Serial.print(positives[i]);        
        } */
    }



  counter=0;
  greenCounter=0;

  }
```

With the for loop commented out, I get these results from the serial.print monitor every 3000 milliseconds:

Number of Hours 1
 Number of Hours 2
 Number of Hours 3
...so on until this:
 Number of Hours 198
 Number o

Note:The 199th actually prints like this.

With the for loop active, results on the serial monitor look like this:

Number of Hours 1
 Number of Spins, Hour 0;0
 Number of Postives, Hour 0;0
 Number of Hours 2
 Number of Spins, Hour 0;0
 Number of Postives, Hour 0;0
 Number of Spins, Hour 1;0
 Number of Postives, Hour 1;0
 Number of Hours 3
 Number of Spins, Hour 0;0
 Number of Postives, Hour 0;0
 Number of Spins, Hour 1;0
 Number of Postives, Hour 1;0
 Number of Spins, Hour 2;0
 Number of Postives, Hour 2;0
 Number of Hours 4

Except this continues all the way up to hour 200, which takes much longer than 300ms.  It then pauses and then starts all over again.  How do I fix numberofhours counting issue so I can store all results from the counter and greenCounter in the proper places in the array that correspond to the numberofhours variable?

Comment: The problem is really simple, when `numberofhours` is greater than 199, you are trying to write out of the `unsigned long spins[200]` and generate na Exception. If you want to continue, the best could be to manage a circular access by replacing `spins[numberofhours]=counter;` by `spins[(numberofhours % 200)]=counter;` (same for `positives[]`).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried the edits you suggested with the for loop still commented out and the output is "Number if Hours x" where x seems to be increasing with the eternal clock or something.  The value got higher than 10,000 in less than 1 minute.  It seems like once the if statement is entered, it does not exit instead of incrementing numberofhours once every 3000ms as intended

Comment: The error is certainly due to that wrong assignment `timer==millis();` instead of `timer=millis();`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Errors like these make me lose my mind.  I really can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

You are continually resetting your counters.  Move the reset inside the if statement.

There seems to be something missing in your code.  Where are you modifying counter and greenCounter?  Also,  numerofhours will increment beyond 199 and you will be indexing out of bounds on the arrays.  You might also want to add Serial.println() to make your output easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The counter and greenCounter variables are actually used to counter the number of  time the corresponding analog voltage pins go over and under the set threshold.  That section of code works exactly as expected, and I isolated the problem to this section, so I made a new sketch with just the timing and array lines.